# How to compress in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, compression, batch-processing

I have a problem about compressing a directory or a file in a batch file. HOw can I do this, Can anybody help me about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There is a good solution to a similar question on a [Post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili), I have copy pasted it below.

CScript  zip.vbs  C:\test3  C:\someArchive.zip

Where zip.vbs contains the following

```
'Get command-line arguments.
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
InputFolder = objArgs(0)
ZipFile = objArgs(1)

'Create empty ZIP file.
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items

objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)

'Required!
wScript.Sleep 2000
```

Comment: I created a bat file which include "CScript zip.vbs C:\Temp C:\someArchive.zip" and I created zip.vbs in same directory. Then, I run the bat file but, it didn't work that I want. Where is my mistake? C:\Temp is the directory which I want to compress.

Comment: There are no error messages. Only I see that it don't compress the folder. Then I created a bat file which include the code that the approved one of this link->   http://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili . It run as individual bat file but when I copy-paste it in another bat file (in if-else block) it doesn't run. There are no problem about if-else, I am sure. I couldn't understand the problem.

Comment: There are an error messages about in my last situation -> C:\Windows\system32\_zipIt.vbs(9, 8) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Invalid character

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 3rd party tool, I suggest [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), which has a command line version you can use in batch.

See [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) for a list of usable commands and examples.

Comment: You could use the built in windows zip command, by calling a object in a vbs.

Comment: @JohnMitchell True, edited answer as a suggestion rather than a requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here you can find two ways without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f) using any external tools .

Better use the [WSH/Jscript script](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) that uses the Shell.Application object.