# How can I compress (/ zip ) and uncompress (/ unzip ) files and folders with batch file without using any external tools?

Tags: .net, zip, jscript, batch-file

I know the similar questions were asked here a lot, but I'm not completely satisfied with the answers (and even with the questions).

The main goal is compatibility - it should be applicable to widest possible range of Windows machines (including [XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP), [Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista), and [Server 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) - which together still holds around 20% of Windows share) and produced files should be usable on Unix/Mac machines (so standard archiving/compression formats are preferable).

*What the options are:*

1. Creating a batch that implements some zip algorithm. Apparently this is possible - but only with single files and using CERTUTIL for binary processing (some machines does not have CERTUTIL by default and is not possible to be installed on Windows XP Home Edition)
2. Using [shell.application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774085(v=vs.85).aspx) through [WSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host). It is the best option according to me. It allows zipping whole directories and is usable on every Windows machine
3. [Makecab](http://ss64.com/nt/makecab.html) - despite its compression is not so portable its available on every windows machine. Some external programs like 7-Zip are capable to extract .CAB content, but it will be not so convenient when files need to be used on Unix/Mac. And while compressing a single file is pretty straightforward, preserving directory structure requires a little bit more effort.
4. Using .NET Framework - not so good option. From .NET 2.0 there is [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx), but it allows compression only of single files. .NET 4.5 has Zip capabilities, but it's not supported on Vista and XP. And even more - .NET is not installed by default on XP and Server 2003, but as it is highly probable to have .NET 2.0 up-to 4.0 it's a considerable option.
5. PowerShell - as it relies on .NET it has same capabilities. It's not installed by default on XP, Server 2003 and Vista, so I'll skip it.

Comment: Does your `Shell.Application` method have the [2GB size limitation](http://www.naterice.com/blog/template_permalink.asp?id=64)?  Also note that ZIP64 format is only supported for `Shell.Application` in [Vista or newer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#ZIP64).

Comment: @DavidRuhmann - The biggest file I've tested it was 1.5gb . Most probably it's size is limited.Will test it and will update .

Comment: I just tested [my `Shell.Application` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27279354/1683264) successfully zipping the directory containing my XP Mode virtual hard disk, which totals about 6.2 gigs.  It compressed to 2.44 gigs.  I then used IZArc to unzip, and all contents extracted without errors with sizes identical to the originals.  This is on Win7 x64.

Comment: @rojo @ DavidRuhmann    - on win8.1x64 the limit for the zip file seems to be around 8gb

Comment: All currently supported Microsoft Windows platforms have PowerShell installed. `Compress-Archive` and `Expand-Archive`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

And here are the answer(s):

#### 1. Using "pure" batch script to zip/unzip file.

It's possible thanks to Frank Westlake's [ZIP.CMD](https://github.com/FrankWestlake/CMD-scripts/blob/master/zip.cmd)  and [UNZIP.CMD](https://github.com/FrankWestlake/CMD-scripts/blob/master/unzip.cmd)(needs admin permissions and requires `FSUTIL` and `CERTUTIL`) .For Win2003 and WinXP it will require [2003 Admin Tool Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16770)  which will install `CERTUTIL`. Be careful as ZIP.CMD syntax is backward  :

```
ZIP.CMD destination.zip source.file
```

And it can zip only single files.

#### 2. Using Shell.Application

I've spent some time to create a single jscript/batch hybrid script for common usage that zips/unzips files and directories (plus few more features).[***Here's a link to it***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) (it became too big to post in the answer).
Can be used directly with its `.bat` extension and does not create any temp files.
I hope the  help message is descriptive enough of how it can be used.

Some examples:

```
// unzip content of a zip to given folder.content of the zip will be not preserved (-keep no).Destination will be not overwritten (-force no)
call zipjs.bat unzip -source C:\myDir\myZip.zip -destination C:\MyDir -keep no -force no

// lists content of a zip file and full paths will be printed (-flat yes)
call zipjs.bat list -source C:\myZip.zip\inZipDir -flat yes

// lists content of a zip file and the content will be list as a tree (-flat no)
call zipjs.bat list -source C:\myZip.zip -flat no

// prints uncompressed size in bytes
zipjs.bat getSize -source C:\myZip.zip

// zips content of folder without the folder itself
call zipjs.bat zipDirItems -source C:\myDir\ -destination C:\MyZip.zip -keep yes -force no

// zips file or a folder (with the folder itslelf)
call zipjs.bat zipItem -source C:\myDir\myFile.txt -destination C:\MyZip.zip -keep yes -force no

// unzips only part of the zip with given path inside
call zipjs.bat unZipItem -source C:\myDir\myZip.zip\InzipDir\InzipFile -destination C:\OtherDir -keep no -force yes
call zipjs.bat unZipItem -source C:\myDir\myZip.zip\InzipDir -destination C:\OtherDir 

// adds content to a zip file
call zipjs.bat addToZip -source C:\some_file -destination C:\myDir\myZip.zip\InzipDir -keep no
call zipjs.bat addToZip -source  C:\some_file -destination C:\myDir\myZip.zip
```

Some known issues during zipping:

- if there's not enough space on the system drive (usually C:) the script could produce various errors , most often the script halts.This is due to *Shell.Application* actively uses **%TEMP%** folder to compress/decompress the data.
- Folders and files that contain unicode symbols in their names cannot be handled by Shell.Application object.
- Max supported size of produced zip files is around 8gb in Vista and above and around 2gb in XP/2003

The script detects if error message pops-up and stops the execution and informs for the possible reasons.At the moment I have no way to detect the text inside the pop-up and give the exact reason for the failure.

#### 3. [Makecab](http://ss64.com/nt/makecab.html)

Compressing a file is easy - `makecab file.txt "file.cab"` . Eventually **[MaxCabinetSize](http://ss64.com/nt/makecab-directives.html)** could be increased.
Compressing a folder requires a usage **DestinationDir** directive (with  relative paths) for every (sub)directory and the files within .
Here's a script:

```
;@echo off

;;;;; rem start of the batch part  ;;;;;
;
;for %%a in (/h /help -h -help) do ( 
;   if /I "%~1" equ "%%~a" if "%~2" equ "" (
;       echo compressing directory to cab file  
;       echo Usage:
;       echo(
;       echo %~nx0 "directory" "cabfile"
;       echo(
;       echo to uncompress use:
;       echo EXPAND cabfile -F:* .
;       echo(
;       echo Example:
;       echo(
;       echo %~nx0 "c:\directory\logs" "logs"
;       exit /b 0
;   )
; )
;
; if "%~2" EQU "" (
;   echo invalid arguments.For help use:
;   echo %~nx0 /h
;   exit /b 1
;)
;
; set "dir_to_cab=%~f1"
;
; set "path_to_dir=%~pn1"
; set "dir_name=%~n1" 
; set "drive_of_dir=%~d1"
; set "cab_file=%~2"
;
; if not exist %dir_to_cab%\ (
;   echo no valid directory passed
;   exit /b 1
;)

;
;break>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf"
;
;setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
;for /d /r "%dir_to_cab%" %%a in (*) do (
;   
;   set "_dir=%%~pna"
;   set "destdir=%dir_name%!_dir:%path_to_dir%=!"
;   (echo(.Set DestinationDir=!destdir!>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   for %%# in ("%%a\*") do (
;       (echo("%%~f#"  /inf=no>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   )
;)
;(echo(.Set DestinationDir=!dir_name!>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   for %%# in ("%~f1\*") do (
;       
;       (echo("%%~f#"  /inf=no>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   )

;makecab /F "%~f0" /f "%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf" /d DiskDirectory1=%cd% /d CabinetNameTemplate=%cab_file%.cab
;rem del /q /f "%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf"
;exit /b %errorlevel%

;;
;;;; rem end of the batch part ;;;;;

;;;; directives part ;;;;;
;;
.New Cabinet
.set GenerateInf=OFF
.Set Cabinet=ON
.Set Compress=ON
.Set UniqueFiles=ON
.Set MaxDiskSize=1215751680;

.set RptFileName=nul
.set InfFileName=nul

.set MaxErrors=1
;;
;;;; end of directives part ;;;;;
```

Example usage:

```
call cabDir.bat ./myDir compressedDir.cab
```

For decompression `EXPAND cabfile -F:* .` can be used.For extraction in  Unix [cabextract](http://www.cabextract.org.uk/) or [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) can be used.

### 4. .NET and GZipStream

I preferred a Jscript.net as it allows a neat hybridization with .bat (no toxic output , and no temp files).Jscript does not allow passing a reference of object to a function so the only way I found to make it work is by reading/writing files byte by byte (so I suppose it's not the fastest way - how buffered reading/writing can be done?)Again can be used only with single files.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:-d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\*jsc.exe"') do (
   set "jsc=%%v"
)

if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
    "%jsc%" /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
)

 %~n0.exe %*

endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%


*/


import System;
import System.Collections.Generic;
import System.IO;
import System.IO.Compression;


    
    function CompressFile(source,destination){
        var sourceFile=File.OpenRead(source);
        var destinationFile=File.Create(destination);
        var output = new  GZipStream(destinationFile,CompressionMode.Compress);
        Console.WriteLine("Compressing {0} to {1}.", sourceFile.Name,destinationFile.Name, false);
        var byteR = sourceFile.ReadByte();
        while(byteR !=- 1){
            output.WriteByte(byteR);
            byteR = sourceFile.ReadByte();
        }
        sourceFile.Close();
        output.Flush();
        output.Close();
        destinationFile.Close();
    }

    function UncompressFile(source,destination){
        var sourceFile=File.OpenRead(source);
        var destinationFile=File.Create(destination);
        
        var input = new GZipStream(sourceFile,
            CompressionMode.Decompress, false);
        Console.WriteLine("Decompressing {0} to {1}.", sourceFile.Name,
                destinationFile.Name);
        
        var byteR=input.ReadByte();
        while(byteR !== -1){
            destinationFile.WriteByte(byteR);
            byteR=input.ReadByte();
        }
        destinationFile.Close();
        input.Close();
        
        
    }
    
var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

    function printHelp(){
        Console.WriteLine("Compress and uncompress gzip files:");
        Console.WriteLine("Compress:");
        Console.WriteLine(arguments[0]+" -c source destination");
        Console.WriteLine("Uncompress:");
        Console.WriteLine(arguments[0]+" -u source destination");
        
        
    }

if (arguments.length!=4){
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong arguments");
    printHelp();
    Environment.Exit(1);
}

switch (arguments[1]){
    case "-c":
    
        CompressFile(arguments[2],arguments[3]);
        break;
    case "-u":
        UncompressFile(arguments[2],arguments[3]);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong arguments");
        printHelp();
        Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

Example usage:

```
//zip
call netzip.bat -c my.file my.zip
//unzip
call netzip.bat -u my.zip my.file
```

### 5. TAR (only for the newest windows builds)

With the latest builds of windows 10 now we have [TAR](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409) command ,though it's not the most backward compatible option:

```
//compress directory
tar -cvf archive.tar c:\my_dir
//extract to dir
tar -xvf archive.tar.gz -C c:\data
//compres to zip format
tar -caf archive.zip c:\my_dir
```

Comment: It is indeed a great collection of solutions. I like most the solution 2 with `zipjs.bat`. But I have an enhancement request for `zipjs.bat`. On __unzip__ of a ZIP file it leaves behind in `%TEMP%` the subdirectories and files used temporarily to extract each file from the ZIP file. It would be good if this hybrid batch file would delete them by itself, see my answer on [How to write a batch file that can unzip a file into a new folder with the same name?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31502536/3074564)

Comment: @Mofi - will check this . I do not create a zips in temp folder - rather this is how the shell.application works.I have two more requests concerning `zipjs.bat` and I hope soon I'll have the time to update it.

Comment: Is option 1. requiring administrative privileges as `fsutil` is used?

Comment: @aschipfl - I don't think so . The command used is `fsUtil usn readData someFile.ext` which does not require admin privileges.

Comment: Thank you! I think this applies to `UNZIP.CMD` too, right?

Comment: @aschipfl hmm.. UNZIP.CMD should require admin permissions as it writes files

Comment: zipjs.bat works very well for me, thank you for this script! Only the option -keep no seems not reliable, sometimes the source folder and some of its contents is not removed. I perform a delete (RD) myself aftwerwards.

Comment: @johey - thanks for the feedback. I'll try to check it till the end of the week.

Comment: ZIP.CMD and UNZIP.cmd links both result in 404 errors on this date.

Comment: Rather than offering your own .bat file as a "solution", i think it would be more informative to explain how your .bat file works.

Comment: __ATTENTION:__ Do __not__ use `zipjs.bat unzip -source C:\Temp\Test\ZipFile.zip -destination C:\Temp\Test -keep no -force yes` as that first results in a __complete__ deletion of the source directory `C:\Temp\Test` being specified also as destination directory and then nothing can be extracted anymore as the ZIP file does not exist anymore nor anything else in `C:\Temp\Test`. The destination directory should be always different to source directory and not a parent directory of the source directory. The destination directory should be best either an empty directory or does not yet exist at all.

Comment: The links to ZIP.CMD and UNZIP.cmd are no longer valid, but they were forked and can be found at https://github.com/Klozz/CMD-scripts/blob/master/zip.cmd and https://github.com/Klozz/CMD-scripts/blob/master/unzip.cmd, respectively.

Answer (score 7):

amazing solutions!

The makecab solution has some issues so here is a fixed version that solves the problem when using directories with blank spaces.

```
;@echo off

;;;;; rem start of the batch part  ;;;;;
;
;for %%a in (/h /help -h -help) do ( 
;   if /I "%~1" equ "%%~a" if "%~2" equ "" (
;       echo compressing directory to cab file  
;       echo Usage:
;       echo(
;       echo %~nx0 "directory" "cabfile"
;       echo(
;       echo to uncompress use:
;       echo EXPAND cabfile -F:* .
;       echo(
;       echo Example:
;       echo(
;       echo %~nx0 "c:\directory\logs" "logs"
;       exit /b 0
;   )
; )
;
; if "%~2" EQU "" (
;   echo invalid arguments.For help use:
;   echo %~nx0 /h
;   exit /b 1
;)
;
; set "dir_to_cab=%~f1"
;
; set "path_to_dir=%~pn1"
; set "dir_name=%~n1" 
; set "drive_of_dir=%~d1"
; set "cab_file=%~2"
; 
; if not exist "%dir_to_cab%\" (
;   echo no valid directory passed
;   exit /b 1
;)

;
;break>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf"
;
;setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
;for /d /r "%dir_to_cab%" %%a in (*) do (
;   
;   set "_dir=%%~pna"
;   set "destdir=%dir_name%!_dir:%path_to_dir%=!"
;   (echo(.Set DestinationDir=!destdir!>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   for %%# in ("%%a\*") do (
;       (echo("%%~f#"  /inf=no>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   )
;)
;(echo(.Set DestinationDir=!dir_name!>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   for %%# in ("%~f1\*") do (
;       
;       (echo("%%~f#"  /inf=no>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   )

;makecab /F "%~f0" /f "%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf" /d DiskDirectory1="%cd%" /d CabinetNameTemplate=%cab_file%.cab
;rem del /q /f "%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf"
;exit /b %errorlevel%

;;
;;;; rem end of the batch part ;;;;;

;;;; directives part ;;;;;
;;
.New Cabinet
.set GenerateInf=OFF
.Set Cabinet=ON
.Set Compress=ON
.Set UniqueFiles=ON
.Set MaxDiskSize=1215751680;

.set RptFileName=nul
.set InfFileName=nul

.set MaxErrors=1
;;
;;;; end of directives part ;;;;;
```

Answer (score 5):

Some examples with powershell using [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.1) and [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7.1):

```
//zipping folder or file:
powershell "Compress-Archive -Path """C:\some_folder""" -DestinationPath """zippedFolder.zip""""

//unzipping folder:
powershell "Expand-Archive -Path """Draftv2.Zip""" -DestinationPath """C:\Reference""""
```

As in the current supported versions of windows these cmd-lets are installed by default.

Another ways with powershell

```
//zip directory
powershell "Add-Type -Assembly """System.IO.Compression.FileSystem""" ;[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("""C:\some_dir""", """some.zip""");"

//unzip directory
powershell "Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" ;[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("""yourfile.zip""", """c:\your\destination""");"
```

Comment: I wanted to zip a folder/directory. Of the two commands shown here for that purpose, only the second one worked for me. Possibly the problem was that the path contained parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

As the answer from @IIde, improved upon the makecab batch script posted by @npocmaka, I evolved it a bit further as well.  Namely, I added a `[-w/-wrapper]` option as a 3rd argument, and changed the default behavior regarding this.

The way the original script worked, the source directory is included as an outer "wrapper" / "container" inside the resulting cab file.  Instead of that, I placed the recursively collected contents of the source directory starting on the *root* from the archive down. If, however, you want to preserve the nesting, you simply pass `-w` as a final argument to my version of this.

Additionally, I changed the recommended decompression utility from `EXPAND` to `EXTRAC32`. The former proved tricky to implement when the "wrapper" directory was not in the archive, where the latter decompresses everything without effort.  (Note that gui utilities e.g. 7-zip are even easier for this purpose though!)

#### Dir2Cab.bat

```
;@echo off

;;;;; rem start of the batch part  ;;;;;
;
;for %%a in (/h /help -h -help) do ( 
;   if /I "%~1" equ "%%~a" if "%~2" equ "" (
;       echo compressing directory to cab file  
;       echo Usage:
;       echo(
;       echo %~nx0 "directory" "cabfile" [-w/-wrapper]
;       echo(
;       echo to uncompress use:
;       echo EXTRAC32 cabfile.cab /E /L .
;       echo(
;       echo Example:
;       echo(
;       echo %~nx0 "c:\directory\logs" "logs" 
;       exit /b 0
;   )
; )
;
; if "%~2" equ "" (
;   echo invalid arguments.For help use:
;   echo %~nx0 -h
;   exit /b 1
;)
;
; set "dir_to_cab=%~f1"
;
; set "path_to_dir=%~pn1"
; set "dir_name=%~n1" 
; set "drive_of_dir=%~d1"
; set "cab_file=%~2"
; 
; if not exist "%dir_to_cab%\" (
;   echo no valid directory passed
;   exit /b 1
;)

; :: Toggle the wrapper directory option
;set "wrapperdir="
;for %%a in (-w -wrapper) do ( 
;   if /I "%~3" equ "%%~a" set "wrapperdir=%dir_name%"
;)

;
;break>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf"
;
;setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

;:: Generate a DDF file via a recursive directory listing
;for /d /r "%dir_to_cab%" %%a in (*) do (
;   
;   set "_dir=%%~pna"
;   set "destdir=%wrapperdir%!_dir:%path_to_dir%=!"
;   (echo(.Set DestinationDir=!destdir!>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   for %%# in ("%%a\*") do (
;       (echo("%%~f#"  /inf=no>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   )
;)
;(echo(.Set DestinationDir=!wrapperdir!>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   for %%# in ("%~f1\*") do (
;       (echo("%%~f#"  /inf=no>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   )

;:: Run makecab against the DDF file 
;makecab /F "%~f0" /f "%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf" /d DiskDirectory1="%cd%" /d CabinetNameTemplate=%cab_file%.cab

;:: You might comment out this DDF file deletion for debugging purposes...
;del /q /f "%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf"

;exit /b %errorlevel%

;;
;;;; rem end of the batch part ;;;;;

;;;; directives part ;;;;;
;;
.New Cabinet
.set GenerateInf=OFF
.Set Cabinet=ON
.Set Compress=ON
.Set UniqueFiles=ON
.Set MaxDiskSize=1215751680;

.set RptFileName=nul
.set InfFileName=nul

.set MaxErrors=1
;;
;;;; end of directives part ;;;;;
```

Answer (score 2):

**CAB.bat** [input] folder or file : pack | .cab or .??_ : unpack | none : pack a `files` subfolder
Will also add a `CAB` entry to right-click SendTo menu for easy handling
Since this one does both tasks seamlessly, it should be preferred over the ugly makecab one - why use hybrid script if you write to temp file anyway?

```
@echo off &echo. &set "ext=%~x1" &title CAB [%1] &rem input file or folder / 'files' folder / unpacks .cab .??_
if "_%1"=="_" if not exist "%~dp0files" echo CAB: No input and no 'files' directory to pack &goto :Exit "do nothing"
if "_%1"=="_" if exist "%~dp0files" call :CabDir "%~dp0files" &goto :Exit "input = none, use 'files' directory -pack" 
for /f "tokens=1 delims=r-" %%I in ("%~a1") do if "_%%I"=="_d" call :CabDir "%~f1" &goto :Exit "input = dir -pack"
if not "_%~x1"=="_.cab" if not "_%ext:~-1%"=="__" call :CabFile "%~f1" &goto :Exit "input = file -pack"
call :CabExtract "%~f1" &goto :Exit "input = .cab or .??_ -unpack" 
:Exit AveYo: script will add a CAB entry to right-click -- SendTo menu
if not exist "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\CAB.bat" copy /y "%~f0" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\CAB.bat" >nul 2>nul
ping -n 6 localhost >nul &title cmd.exe &exit /b
:CabExtract %1:[.cab or .xx_]
echo %1 &pushd "%~dp1" &mkdir "%~n1" >nul 2>nul &expand -R "%~1" -F:* "%~n1" &popd &goto :eof
:CabFile %1:[filename]
echo %1 &pushd "%~dp1" &makecab /D CompressionType=LZX /D CompressionLevel=7 /D CompressionMemory=21 "%~nx1" "%~n1.cab" &goto :eof   
:CabDir %1:[directory]
dir /a:-D/b/s "%~1"
set "ddf="%temp%\ddf""
echo/.New Cabinet>%ddf%
echo/.set Cabinet=ON>>%ddf%
echo/.set CabinetFileCountThreshold=0;>>%ddf%
echo/.set Compress=ON>>%ddf%
echo/.set CompressionType=LZX>>%ddf%
echo/.set CompressionLevel=7;>>%ddf%
echo/.set CompressionMemory=21;>>%ddf%
echo/.set FolderFileCountThreshold=0;>>%ddf%
echo/.set FolderSizeThreshold=0;>>%ddf%
echo/.set GenerateInf=OFF>>%ddf%
echo/.set InfFileName=nul>>%ddf%
echo/.set MaxCabinetSize=0;>>%ddf%
echo/.set MaxDiskFileCount=0;>>%ddf%
echo/.set MaxDiskSize=0;>>%ddf%
echo/.set MaxErrors=1;>>%ddf%
echo/.set RptFileName=nul>>%ddf%
echo/.set UniqueFiles=ON>>%ddf%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "%~dp1"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%D in ('dir /a:-D/b/s "%~1"') do (
 set "DestinationDir=%%~dpD" &set "DestinationDir=!DestinationDir:%~1=!" &set "DestinationDir=!DestinationDir:~0,-1!"
 echo/.Set DestinationDir=!DestinationDir!;>>%ddf%
 echo/"%%~fD"  /inf=no;>>%ddf%
)
makecab /F %ddf% /D DiskDirectory1="" /D CabinetNameTemplate=%~nx1.cab &endlocal &popd &del /q /f %ddf% &goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

Working prototype with [makeself](https://makeself.io/), [certutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil) and [busybox](https://frippery.org/busybox/):

https://github.com/hemnstill/makeself/releases/tag/release-2.4.5-cmd

pros:

- single `.bat` file that working on Windows 2016+ and many Linux.
- impressive command line args. potentially support different archive formats.
- no external dependensies. only `certuril.exe` is used to extract `busybox.exe`

cons:

- payload size ~900kb (can be slightly reduced with upx)
- virustotal result: 9/56 (antiviruses don't like it when certutil.exe is used to extract the payload)
- `busybox.exe` does not support all features from makeself cli.