# Batch script to create a ZIP file out of a list of stated files and folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, zip

I have the following files tree

```
|
|--/BlueFolder1/
|----Blue.txt
|----Blue2.exe
|--/BlueFolder2/
|----Blue.exe
|-Blue2.exe
|-Red.md
|-Blue.txt
|-MySuperAwesomeScript.bat
```

I need to make a batch script to ZIP all the "blue" files into a `BlueFiles.zip` archive.

I'm really null at these technologies but I think I shall list the files I want to zip, or if possible, declare which files to IGNORE.

i've found this batch script which works like a charm, but it doesn't let me chose which files not/include.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET sourceDirPath=%1
IF [%2] EQU [] (
  SET destinationDirPath="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
) ELSE (
  SET destinationDirPath="%2"
)
IF [%3] EQU [] (
  SET destinationFileName="%~n1%.zip"
) ELSE (
  SET destinationFileName="%3"
)
SET tempFilePath=%TEMP%\FilesToZip.txt
TYPE NUL > %tempFilePath%

FOR /F "DELIMS=*" %%i IN ('DIR /B /S /A-D "%sourceDirPath%"') DO (
  SET filePath=%%i
  SET dirPath=%%~dpi
  SET dirPath=!dirPath:~0,-1!
  SET dirPath=!dirPath:%sourceDirPath%\=!
  SET dirPath=!dirPath:%sourceDirPath%=!
  ECHO .SET DestinationDir=!dirPath! >> %tempFilePath%
  ECHO "!filePath!" >> %tempFilePath%
)

MAKECAB /D MaxDiskSize=0 /D CompressionType=MSZIP /D Cabinet=ON /D Compress=ON /D UniqueFiles=OFF /D DiskDirectoryTemplate=%destinationDirPath% /D CabinetNameTemplate=%destinationFileName%  /F %tempFilePath% > NUL 2>&1

DEL setup.inf > NUL 2>&1
DEL setup.rpt > NUL 2>&1
DEL %tempFilePath% > NUL 2>&1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f)

Despite Makecab uses deflate algorithm the final format won't be zip but cab.
`MaxDiskSize=0` will set the size to its default (i.e. floppy disk)
To preserve directory structure you 'll need to set `DestinationDir` after each directory change so you'll need additional directive file.In the link above there's a ready to use script that will cab a directory.You'll to exclude not-blue files you can edit the directive file.Check [MAKECAB](http://ss64.com/nt/makecab.html) info.

this should add only blue files to the directive.

```
;@echo off

;;;;; rem start of the batch part  ;;;;;
; if "%~2" EQU "" (
;   echo invalid arguments.For help use:
;   echo %~nx0 /h
;)
;for %%a in (/h /help -h -help) do ( 
;   if "%~1" equ "%%~a" (
;       echo compressing directory to cab file  
;       echo %~nx0 directory cabfile
;       echo to uncompress use:
;       echo EXPAND cabfile -F:* .
;   )
; )
;
; set "dir_to_cab=%~f1"
;
; set "path_to_dir=%~pn1"
; set "dir_name=%~n1" 
; set "drive_of_dir=%~d1"
; set "cab_file=%~2"
;
; if not exist %dir_to_cab%\ (
;   echo no valid directory passed
;   exit /b 1
;)

;
;break>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf"
;
;setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
;for /d /r "%dir_to_cab%" %%a in (*) do (
;   
;   set "_dir=%%~pna"
;   set "destdir=%dir_name%!_dir:%path_to_dir%=!"
;   (echo(.Set DestinationDir=!destdir!>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   for %%# in ("%%a\*") do (
;       (echo("%%~s#"  /inf=no>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   )
;)
;(echo(.Set DestinationDir=!dir_name!>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   for %%# in ("%~f1\*blue*") do (
;       
;       (echo("%%~s#"  /inf=no>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   )

;makecab /F "%~f0" /f "%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf" /d DiskDirectory1=%cd% /d CabinetNameTemplate=%cab_file%.cab
;del /q /f "%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf"
;exit /b %errorlevel%

;;
;;;; rem end of the batch part ;;;;;

;;;; directives part ;;;;;
;;
.New Cabinet
.set GenerateInf=OFF
.Set Cabinet=ON
.Set Compress=ON
.Set UniqueFiles=ON
.Set MaxDiskSize=1215751680;

.set RptFileName=nul
.set InfFileName=nul

.set MaxErrors=1
;;
;;;; end of directives part ;;;;;
```

But if you want a zip format check the *shell.application* solution which will allow to add items to already created zip.