# Batch file to open a zip file in windows

Tags: batch-file

I have a .apk file at path `C:\BatchTest`
I want to do the following things using a batch file.

Rename the .apk file `test.apk` to `test.zip`

Open `test.zip`

Go to a folder `abc` inside `test.zip` and delete its contents.

Rename `test.zip` back to `test.apk`

Any suggestions how can this be done.

Comment: Check my zipjs.bat here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/ can remove content from a zip , but I'm a little bit busy at the moment.Later will post a solution for you without using any external tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use the [command-line version of 7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/a/7za920.zip), using parameters you can adapt the zip, See [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) for examples. The renaming part can be done in a batch, i suppose that won't be a problem ?

I you master a scripting language like Ruby this can all be done in a script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @peter. I was however looking for a generic batch file which has all the commands.

Comment: That is what i propose in the first part, you can put these commands in a batch.

Comment: There is no built-in handling of compressed files in batch. However, there are workarounds, as npocmaka wrote. I don't see an advantage using this kind of blackhack. I recommend: use 7-Zip. You can use the exe as "portable" if you don't want to install it.

Comment: @MichaelS: did i say there is build in handling ? I say to use 7zip command-line version

Comment: You've misunderstood my comment. I'm shearing your oppinion and recommending to use 7zip, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is without external tools:

```
@echo off

copy test.apk test.zip /Y
rmdir abc /s /q >nul 2>nul 

call zipjs.bat unZipItem -source %cd%\test.zip\abc -destination %cd%\abc -keep no -force no
rmdir abc /s /q >nul 2>nul
```

you'll need [zipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) in the same directory.Though you dont need to rename the file.Extension does not matter.