# batch file for compressing folder in same directory

Tags: batch-file

I want to zip a folder using batch file. Here's my code for zip.bat:

```
CScript zip.vbs E:\app E:\app.zip
```

zip.vbs has the following code:

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments

InputFolder = objArgs(0)

ZipFile = objArgs(1)

'Create empty ZIP file.

CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)


Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items

objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)

'Required!

wScript.Sleep 2000000
```

This code is ziiping the folder properly but i dont want to mention any drive name. I want that in any drive if i keep my bat file n app folder then after running the bat file it should zip the folder.
Is there any code for this???

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `FileSystemObject` and to use [GetAbsolutePathName](http://ss64.com/vb/filesystemobject.html) function - shell.application namespaces does not accept relative paths.

Though using sleep is bad idea - it will either make the script too slow or will will interrupt the zipping.The better idea is to count the items in the source and in the destination as the zipping is transactional and files count is a robust way ti check if the operation is done.

You can check also my **[zipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat)** which also uses **Shell.Application** but everything is packed in a hybrid `jscript\.bat` script (it even will no create temp files).It is able to process relative paths ,and comparatively robust (one of the most used scripts I've written - so I had some feedback and needed to fix numerous of bugs :-)  )

More info here: [How can I compress (/ zip ) and uncompress (/ unzip ) files and folders with batch file without using any external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f)

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"):
InputFolder =  fso.GetAbsolutePathName(objArgs(0)):



ZipFile = objArgs(1)

'Create empty ZIP file.

CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)


Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items

objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)

'Required!

wScript.Sleep 2000000
```

Comment: can u share some simple code .. the one which u provided is not working

Comment: @Dimple - something is not working with zipjs.bat? Can you provide more info.Will update my answer.