# copy some files from the most recent folders with a filter and unzip them . ? bat or c#?

Tags: c#, batch-file, copy, zip

I need to be able to copy files from a network drive to another folder.  My files are in different folders on the same drive. I need everthing that contains the keyword "Fiber" from all the folders that have the most recent date. I have a script that does that correctly. The problem is that my script only work if I specify the date.I want to be able to do that without having to always change the date manually.

```
xcopy R:\*fiber*.zip C:\Users\john.doe\Desktop\shape /s /d:06-20-2015
```

After I have my files, I want to be able to unzip them because they are zip files. Am I able to do this with a .bat files or can I do that with a c# script. Could you tell me how to fix my two problems.

Thanks.

Comment: With a little bat script magic you can get the date: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/956/windows-batch-file-bat-to-get-current-date-in-mmddyyyy-format/

Comment: I'm not sure what you searched for before, but there are already extremely thorough answers about [getting the date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us/19799236#19799236) and [unzipping files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f).