# How to write a batch file that can unzip a file into a new folder with the same name?

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a batch script that will allow me to unzip a .zip file into a new folder that has the same name as the zip file. I cannot assume that I have some program to unzip the file; it has to work as if the computer is brand new.

For example, if I have a group of zip files named a1, b2, c3, and d4, I want their contents to go into 4 different folders labeled a1, b2, c3, d4. It doesn't need to be concise, it just has to work.

Answer (score 1):

Read excellent topic [How can I compress (zip) and uncompress (unzip) files and folders with batch file without using any external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28043589/3074564) written by [npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka).

I suggest to use the second solution: **Using Shell.Application**

The task can be done with [zipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) also written by [npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka) with a batch file with just a few lines:

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.zip) do call "%~dp0zipjs.bat" unzip -source "%%~fI" -destination "%%~dpnI\" -force yes
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /AD /B "%TEMP%\*.zip" 2^>nul') do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -h "%TEMP%\%%~D"
    rd /S /Q "%TEMP%\%%~D" 2>nul
)
```

The hybrid batch file `zipjs.bat` must be in same folder as the batch file with the two lines above.

Running in a command prompt window `call /?` explains `%~dp0` which means drive and path of argument 0 of batch file without surrounding quotes ending always with a backslash. Argument 0 of a called batch file is the name of the batch file, see also [What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/)

Help of command **for** displayed on running in a command prompt window `for /?` explains

- `%%~fI` - full file/folder name without surrounding quotes, and
- `%%~dpnI` - drive, path and name of a file/folder without surrounding quotes and without extension

for loop variables like `call /?` does for batch parameters/arguments.

The second **for** loop finds all subdirectories in directory for temporary files with `.zip` in directory name, removes the hidden attribute and deletes those subdirectories. This is necessary as `zipjs.bat` first extracts each file into a newly created subdirectory in directory for temporary files and leaves them there after successful extraction.