# Passing relative path in called batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to call **zipjs.bat** file which takes path as argument. 
I am calling the .bat file trough another .bat file called **start.bat**.
Both files aren't at the same place in the file system, they reside in different folders.

**zipjs.bat** reside in `\batch` and the **start.bat** resides in `\odt`

The file that is to be passed as an argument to **zipjs.bat** resides in the same folder as start.bat.

This way(using absolute path for `-source`) everything works fine:

```
call ..\batch\zipjs.bat unzip -source C:\Users\rmrd001\git\xslt-framework\Product\dita\transformations\paragraphs\odt\source.odt.zip -destination .\MyDir -keep yes -force no
pause
```

Above the `-source` takes absolute path. But when I change the absolute path with relative one, like this: `-source .\source.odt.zip` it doesn't work. I tried with paths relative to start.bat - `.\source.odt.zip` and relative to zipjs.bat - `..\odt\source.odt.zip` without success though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve absolute path from relative path and/or file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645843/resolve-absolute-path-from-relative-path-and-or-file-name)

Comment: Since the START.bat and your source are one in the same then just use the directory the batch file exists in. `%~dp0`

Answer (score 1):

The perhaps easiest method would be using `%~dp0` which expands to path of `start.bat` ending with a backslash as suggested by [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman).

I suggest additionally to clean up the directory for temporary files after making the decompression as [zipjs.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28043695/3074564) currently updated last time on 2015-03-17 by [npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka) does not do it, see answer on [How to write a batch file that can unzip a file into a new folder with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31502536/3074564)

```
@echo off
call ..\batch\zipjs.bat unzip -source "%~dp0source.odt.zip" -destination .\MyDir -keep yes -force no
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /AD /B "%TEMP%\*source.odt.zip" 2^>nul') do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -h "%TEMP%\%%~D"
    rd /S /Q "%TEMP%\%%~D" 2>nul
)
pause
```

Comment: After running the for loop, remains a file named `nul)` and no further command are executed into the  bat file.

Comment: Are you sure that you use the code EXACTLY as I posted? Do you have tried those 7 lines? I suppose you use a slightly different batch file with redirecting a possible error messages of command __dir__ to device __nul__ wrong resulting in redirecting output to a file `nul)`. Please check your code and compare it with my code character by character.