# How to write a batch file to compress subfolders inside themselves

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I'm very new to working with batch files but I'm trying to achieve the following

I have a folder `C:\...\...\...\evidence`
In it are subfolders, the names of these can vary, can contain letters numbers and spaces. Let's say;

> - Equations
> - Microscopy
> - images
> - Data
> - 10052011

What I'd like to do is compress all the contents of the subfolder into a file `{Subfoldername}.zip` so `Equations.zip` in equations and delete the now zipped contents.

I can use native zipping or `7zip` and I can work with vb if necessary.

Comment: Let me make it clear. So you want to zip only subfolders, or all files (one by one) in the subfolders?

Comment: take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch

Answer (score 0):

a look at the help output of 7za.exe is helpful.
eg.

```
for /D %%a in (*) do (
  7za.exe a -r "%%a.zip" "%%a" && rmdir /s /q "%%a"
)
```

will iterate all folders, zip them recoursively, and then remove them if zipping was successful (returned 0).