# scan zip files and move files to another directory using a batch file from the command line on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command

I am working on a batch file and trying to write the correct windows commands.

1) Command-line from Windows

2) Use commands to scan the zip file so that it will look inside of the zip file for a specific string in the file within the zip file.

3) If the scan finds that specific string in the file that is within the zip file then move that zip file to another specified directory.

Is it possible using dos commands within a batch file?

I want to learn more on this. Anyone have any guidance or suggestions?

Comment: Different DOS versions come with different set of commands, so it's hard to tell if this is doable or not, you can try to see if your target DOS has these commands: zip (or unzip), grep (or findstr), move, mkdir (or md), and del.

Comment: where do you search for a strings? inside the files or in the file names?

Comment: you can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat)

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the link. I know with Winrar that I can run window command line to have it scan inside of the zip file without having to unzip and look for specific string but Winrar will not move the files that are found in the scan results to another directory.

Comment: I am wanting to scan the zip files without having to unzipping them and look for the specific string. Then if any of the zip files contain that string then move that zip file to another directory.