# jscript - The specified module could not be found

Tags: batch-file, jscript, activexobject

Got this error after running Zipjs.bat from solution 2. at:

[How can I compress (/ zip ) and uncompress (/ unzip ) files and folders with batch file without using any external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat)

I don't think the issue is with this specific jscript, but have narrowed it down to this line in it:

```
Var ShellObj=new ActiveXObject ("Shell.Application");
```

When running the same jscript yesterday it was fine - no error.

So any ideas why my system can't see Shell.Application or whether that is even the problem. How to test this and what a possible solution is?

My computer isn't connected to the internet so it's not malware.

I'm running XP Pro SP3

Comment: you can check if windows script host is enabled - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198684.aspx

Comment: `Shell.Application` is a windows built-in object - some kind of programmable windows explorer.It is not accessible through MSHTA applications I think. Is there any other errors pop-ups? Are there files with with names with non Latin charater that you're trying to zip?

Comment: JScript is case-sensitive. You have to write `var`, not `Var`.

Comment: @Bill sorry I typed it by hand using my phone which defaulted to capital for the first letter of the first word. The real code is all lowercase var. Nicely spotted though.

Comment: @npocmaka I'm running the jscript straight from dos so mshta isn't being used. Like I said it was working before. I didn't write the jscript. Just copied it from the link in the question. But I'll redownload the example to make sure nothing has changed, will check about latin characters and will make sure the script host is happy and get back with the results. Thanks for the ideas. Every bit will help to triangulate the cause :o)