# Makecab white spaces

Tags: batch-file, cab

I need to create cab file  for nested folder .

so I sreate ddf file that looks :

```
.OPTION EXPLICIT ; Will Generate errors for mistakes
 .Set Compress=on
 .Set Cabinet=on

 ; Destination Folder
 .Set DiskDirectory1= my Directory


 ; File name for the new cab file
 .Set CabinetNameTemplate=Sample.cab 

//----------------
```

now in the bat file I insert the list of all files to the ddf file :

```
cd %folderDir%

@echo off
call :treeProcess
goto :eos


:treeProcess

for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /a:-d/b 2^>nul ') do echo %%~fa >>%pathDdfFile%

for /D %%d in (*) do (
   echo .Set DestinationDir=%%d >>%pathDdfFile%
 cd %%d
    call :treeProcess
    cd ..
)
goto :eof

:eos

cd \

//---------------
```

when I run :

```
makecab  /F  %pathDdfFile%  /L C:\temp
```

its return me :

> unexpected text : one file

all files that have space in there name  make problem/
what should I do ?

Comment: so you want to cab a whole directory?

Comment: you can try with `for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /a:-d/b 2^>nul ') do echo %%~fa >>"%pathDdfFile%"`  (double quotes around the file path)

Comment: Thanks , but the ddf file that I create looks fine , the problem is in files that have space in the name  like :
.Set DestinationDir=Mydir
c:\tmp 1 2 3.dll

then I get 
ERROR : Unexpected text : 3.dll

Comment: Oh ok I understand !!
 thank you very much

for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /a:-d/b 2^>nul ') do echo "%%~fa" >>%pathDdfFile%

"c\temp 1 2 3.dll"
the cab is create but when I try to open it I get :
can not open file as archive

Answer (score -1):

You can [check this script](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/makecab/cabdir.bat) that will cab a directory recursively.Example:

```
call cabdir.bat "C:\someDir" some.cab
```

You can also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat)