# Copy command for folders with \..\ and \= names with .bat files

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

I searched everywhere over google and there doesn't seem to be any solution.
Xcopy, copy, robocopy, parsing as literal string via variable, wildcard characters..

```
copy C:\soulworker\datas\bin\Table\nf2\data12.v   C:\soulworker\datas\=true_english\

for /R C:\soulworker\datas\bin\Table\nf2\English\ %%f in (*.res) do copy %%f  C:\soulworker\datas\bin\Table\nf2\data12.zip\..\bin\Table\
```

Comment: It's not possible for `..` to be part of a file path; `..` is a special directory that is built in to every directory and directs to the directory above it.

Comment: Not sure why I'm downvoted for asking a valid question, but it is part of a zip file directory that I extracted. https://i.snag.gy/jAIKnO.jpg https://i.snag.gy/AMxC7O.jpg

Comment: That's not the extracted path; the extracted path won't have `.zip` anywhere in it. You've mistakenly taken the path from _inside_ the zip file. Don't do that.

Comment: Alright my bad, however there is absolutely no way to automate this because it is an invalid file path (as a .bat file) besides overwriting the files manually by opening it as a zip (?).

Comment: Also, it's not working because your `for` loop is trying to copy files from a directory and put them inside of a zip file. That will never ever work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat to create zip files.

Comment: It must follow this exact format in order to be repacked using a xor55 repacker; I looked a little into the link- will it allow me to recreate this zip file with the ... structure \..\bin\Table\?

Comment: Perhaps people downvoted because they miss a question in your post (you know, a sentence with a question mark at the end); you don't state what is going wrong with your code or if an error message appears, you don't even tell what you want to achieve; all this was enough reason for me to downvote...

Answer (score 1):

On `=` *Equals Sign* in path or file name, read [`cmd` Syntax: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html):

> **Delimiters**
>
> Delimiters separate one parameter from the next - they split the
>   command line up into words.
>
> Parameters are most often separated by spaces, but any of the
>   following are also valid delimiters:
>
> - Comma (,)
> - Semicolon (;)
> - Equals (=)
> - Space ( )
> - Tab (     )

To keep a delimiter in file or path name, use double quotes as follows:

```
copy C:\soulworker\datas\bin\Table\nf2\data12.v "C:\soulworker\datas\=true_english\"
```

On using `..` doubled *Full Stop*, read [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Use two consecutive periods (..) as a directory component in a path to
>   represent the parent of the current directory.

For instance, all

```
dir C:\soulworker\datas\bin\Table\nf2\data12.zip\..\bin\Table\
dir C:\soulworker\datas\bin\Table\nf2\data12Xzip\..\bin\Table\
dir C:\soulworker\datas\bin\Table\nf2\foobar.exe\..\bin\Table\
dir C:\soulworker\datas\bin\Table\nf2\foobarABCD\..\bin\Table\
```

would resolve to

```
dir C:\soulworker\datas\bin\Table\nf2\bin\Table\
```

even if skipped directory component in a path contains inadmissible characters e.g. `*` (asterisk), `?`  (question mark) or `:` (colon), see next example:

```
==> dir /B /S c:\windows\foo***...???:::\..\system32\notepad.exe
c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe

==>
```

The `\foo***...???:::` path part (preceding `\..`) is not parsed at all…