# Iterating through the files and extracting only if its a zip folder using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, zip, file-extension

I need to iterate through all the files in the current folder and extract them only if its a zip file. So I wrote the below batch script. But I am getting an error saying

```
"=="."zip" was unexpected at this time
```

Below is the batch script I wrote.

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
for /r %%i in (*) do if %%i "%Extension%"==".zip" (
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
Call :UnZipFile "G:\NewUpdates\ExtractedStuff" %%i
exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
)
pause
```

what am I doing wrong here? Please advice.

Comment: `%extension%` has no special meaning. Generically you solve the above missing variable by `if "%var%"=="whatever"`. But you want `%%~xi` see the end of `for /?` for help.

Comment: Or `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s c:\somefolder\*.zip') do echo %%A` See `dir /?`, `for /?`.

Comment: @Noodles', why `for /F`? `for /R %%i in (*.zip) do ` suffices...

Comment: You have included the sub-routine `UnZipFile` in the `for /R` loop, but you should not do that; place the `)` immediately before `exit /B`; before the `)` put `endlocal` to not exceed the nesting depth of `setlocal` in your loop...

Comment: creating and deleting extraction script will slow down your script dramatically.You can just use `WScript.Arguments` instead of `%1` and `%2` and do not change the vbs file on each iteration.You can check also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading an undefined variable `%Extension%`, and you have two expressions on the left side of the `==` in the `if` statement, which is a syntax error.

To get the file name extension of an item iterated by a `for` loop, use the `~x` modifier (type `for /?` on command prompt to find out more about that), like `%%~xi` in your code:

```
if /i "%%~xi"==".zip" ( ... )
```

The `/i` switch makes the comparison case-insensitive, which is recommended here as Windows treats file names in the same manner.

---

However, in your situation you do not need the `if` statement at all for checking the file name extension, because you can let `for` do that job:

```
for /r %%i in (*.zip) do ( ... )
```

This loop iterates through `*.zip` files only.

---

There is another issue in your code: the sub-routine `:UnZipFile` is part of the loop body, and so there is and `exit /b` inside of the loop.

The sub-routine must be outside of the loop. When `call` is executed, the current contexts of parenthesised blocks of code are not known in the sub-routine, so it will not be considered ended as soon as the loop-ending `)` appears, rather a syntax error arises. Hence you need to move the `)` from the very bottom to a new line *before* `exit /b` (if you place it after, the `exit` command will break the loop).

Since you have `setlocal` inside of your loop, you need to put also `endlocal` (immediately before the `)`) in order not to exceed the `setlocal` nesting limit. However, if you use full paths inside of the loop, you do not need `setlocal`/`endlocal`. Instead I would move `setlocal`/`endlocal` into the sub-routine to localise the environment variables used therein.

---

I am not sure if you intend to change to the directory where the script is stored by `cd /d %~dp0`, but I think you want the full path to the currently iterated `*.zip` file in your loop, right? If so, remove the `cd` command and use `%%~fi` in your `call` command line.

---

Finally, quotation is not optimal throughout the entire code. For example, it is always a good idea to quote file paths and names as they may contain white-spaces or some other characters that are considered as delimiters by the command interpreter or have some other special meaning to it.

Also in the sub-routine you should quote the paths provided as arguments, and access them as `"%~1"`, for instance, to get them properly quoted (type `call /?` to see that the `~` removes surrounding quotes potentionally delivered by the command line).

And the best `set` syntax is: `set "vbs=%temp%\_.vbs"`; so the quotes do not become part of the value and you have always *one* place to put quotation marks -- namely when *reading* (expanding) the variable, like `"%vbs%"`.

---

Finally, let me recommend you to use indention so that the code becomes much more legible and maintainable.

---

Here is the fixed code:

```dos
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
for /r %%i in ("*.zip") do (
    Call :UnZipFile "G:\NewUpdates\ExtractedStuff" "%%~fi"
)
exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
    setlocal
    set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
    if exist "%vbs%" del /f /q "%vbs%"
     >"%vbs%" echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    >>"%vbs%" echo If NOT fso.FolderExists("%~1") Then
    >>"%vbs%" echo fso.CreateFolder("%~1")
    >>"%vbs%" echo End If
    >>"%vbs%" echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    >>"%vbs%" echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace("%~2").items
    >>"%vbs%" echo objShell.NameSpace("%~1").CopyHere(FilesInZip)
    >>"%vbs%" echo Set fso = Nothing
    >>"%vbs%" echo Set objShell = Nothing
    cscript //nologo "%vbs%"
    if exist "%vbs%" del /f /q "%vbs%"
    endlocal
    pause
```

Comment: hey how can I extract the zip files of sub folders into the subfolders itself? Currently G:\NewUpdates\ExtractedStuff folder has 3 sub folders and I need to extract the relevant zip files into the folders they are now itself. That is G:\NewUpdates\ExtractedStuff\updater\test.zip should extract to G:\NewUpdates\ExtractedStuff\updater\. I triedCall :UnZipFile %%~pi "%%~fi" but its not working :(

Comment: Also is there a way to do the extraction silently? I want it overwrite existing files without porpmting me with anything

Comment: I think the `call` command line should be changed to extract to the folder where the ZIP file is located: `Call :UnZipFile "%%~dpi." "%%~fi"`; in your attempt there is no drive letter (`~d`), no quotes and there is a trailing `\ ` when using `~p`/`~dp` which might also cause trouble (that is why I appended the `.`); I don't know how to accomplish silent extraction, but without prompting, but you could force deletion of the destination folder content (except the ZIP itself, of course, if it is in the destination directory also) by the `del` command (its `/S` and `/Q` switches might help too)...

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to simplify the search for zip files by filtering them in the for command , rather than check for file extensions

Use below command :

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /a:-d /b ^| findstr /r ".zip$"') do echo %%a
```

The above command will list all zip files in your directory , now you can play with them the way you want

Hope this helps.