# Moving Files With Batch

Tags: batch-file, installation

How would I program a batch file to move files around? I am implementing mods into a game folder. I want to make it like an installer, so when you run the batch file, it moves everything over to the correct folder to be used in a game. Would it be possible to pull files out of a zipped folder with the batch file?

Comment: [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/) and [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx) offer both a Windows command line reference (click on the links). The command to move files is ... __move__. What a surprise, isn't it. There is no `zipped folder`. There is a ZIP archive file. Extracting files from a ZIP archive is possible, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat But I suggest to create a self-extracting archive which can be done for example with *WinRAR* easily without any coding skills.

Comment: @Mofi doesn't winrar cost money?

Comment: Yes, *WinRAR* is shareware and costs a small amount of money. But it is worth the money. The time you need to code costs most likely more than the *WinRAR* license which includes unlimited free updates to future versions. And as a full functional shareware application not limited in testing period, you can nevertheless use *WinRAR* now to create the self-extracting ZIP or RAR archive. *WinRAR* SFX archives handle also the elevation to administrator/trusted installer account often needed to install something into program files folders of Windows.

Comment: @Mofi oh ok, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
    move C:\folder1*.* C:\folder2