# How to add files to a ZIP file using VB script faster?

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I want to add all files of a  directory into a ZIP file. I use the code below from [Can you zip a file from the command prompt using ONLY Windows' built-in capability to zip files?](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/) But this VB script is very slow.

How can I make this action faster?

```
'Get command-line arguments.
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
InputFolder = objArgs(0)
ZipFile = objArgs(1)

'Create empty ZIP file.
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items

objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)

'Required!
wScript.Sleep 2000
```

Comment: You can't. You are using shell objects which are slow. Use a program like winzip http://www.winzip.com/prodpagecl.html

Comment: There's a free component I learned about from Rob Vander Woud - X-Zip.. he has some code samples here. I don't think you could do this natively but that X-zip seems to be useful for your use-case. Using a language like C++/C# might be optimial to achieve what you're looking for though. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_zip.php

Comment: There are lots of freeware and shareware archivers supporting ZIP like 7-Zip, Info-ZIP, WinRAR, WinZip, etc. written for adding files and directories into a file using ZIP compression. They are all much faster than what Windows offers by default. See also [How can I compress (zip) and uncompress (unzip) files and folders with batch file without using any external tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/)

Comment: If you use WinZip, there is a command line utility kit to be installed. 7-zip is good.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer using Batch files this is the code:

```
@echo off

echo Iam.zip

Move test.txt Iam.zip
```