# How to unzip a file using batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have coded a batch file to unzip a file as follows:

```
unzip images.zip

exit
```

But its not working. Its for creating exe file using IExpress.

What is the code to unzip a file?

Comment: How did you zip the file?

Comment: Do you actually have a program named unzip installed on your computer because Windows does not have a native console application to zip and unzip.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat)  and the second option

Answer (score 4):

The other answers require additional software to be installed. Here is a solution using PowerShell (included in Windows 7 and upwards):

```
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { $shell = New-Object -COM Shell.Application; $target = $shell.NameSpace('C:\extractToThisDirectory'); $zip = $shell.NameSpace('C:\extractThis.zip'); $target.CopyHere($zip.Items(), 16); }"
```

This uses the built-in extract functionality of the Explorer and will also show the typical extract progress window. The second parameter `16` to `CopyHere` is a "yes to all" for possible questions while extraction.

Answer (score 3):

the following utility can do what you want

https://mega.nz/#!VMISDCaD!gEFVVWYN5ODwbtJm4aXNjQW3uVqcUyhqb-DOf0aOmH0

the script to use these .exe files

to zip compress a single file

```
zip.exe "C:/path/to/file.extenxion" "zipfilename"
```

to zip compress all files in a folder

```
zip.exe "C:/path/to/files/*.*" "zipfilename"
```

or if you want to unzip

```
unzip.exe zipfilename
```

note that you dont need to add the .zip extension to make it work

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of unziping images.zip with winrar and copying it to `Output` on the desktop in batch

```
@ECHO ON
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Winrar\WinRAR.exe" x "%userprofile%\Desktop\images.zip" *.* "%userprofile%\Desktop\Output\"
pause
```