# Semicolons in the beginning of line - batch

Tags: batch-file

I am pretty new to batch programming. I have found the program mentioned here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat) in the part of the accepted answer of "Makecab". I am inserting it here:

```
;@echo off

;;;;; rem start of the batch part  ;;;;;
; if "%~2" EQU "" (
;   echo invalid arguments.For help use:
;   echo %~nx0 /h
;)
;for %%a in (/h /help -h -help) do ( 
;   if "%~1" equ "%%~a" (
;       echo compressing directory to cab file  
;       echo %~nx0 directory cabfile
;       echo to uncompress use:
;       echo EXPAND cabfile -F:* .
;   )
; )
;
; set "dir_to_cab=%~f1"
;
; set "path_to_dir=%~pn1"
; set "dir_name=%~n1" 
; set "drive_of_dir=%~d1"
; set "cab_file=%~2"
;
; if not exist %dir_to_cab%\ (
;   echo no valid directory passed
;   exit /b 1
;)

;
;break>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf"
;
;setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
;for /d /r "%dir_to_cab%" %%a in (*) do (
;   
;   set "_dir=%%~pna"
;   set "destdir=%dir_name%!_dir:%path_to_dir%=!"
;   (echo(.Set DestinationDir=!destdir!>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   for %%# in ("%%a\*") do (
;       (echo("%%~s#"  /inf=no>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   )
;)
;(echo(.Set DestinationDir=!dir_name!>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   for %%# in ("%~f1\*") do (
;       
;       (echo("%%~s#"  /inf=no>>"%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf")
;   )

;makecab /F "%~f0" /f "%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf" /d DiskDirectory1=%cd% /d CabinetNameTemplate=%cab_file%.cab
;del /q /f "%tmp%\makecab.dir.ddf"
;exit /b %errorlevel%

;;
;;;; rem end of the batch part ;;;;;

;;;; directives part ;;;;;
;;
.New Cabinet
.set GenerateInf=OFF
.Set Cabinet=ON
.Set Compress=ON
.Set UniqueFiles=ON
.Set MaxDiskSize=1215751680;

.set RptFileName=nul
.set InfFileName=nul

.set MaxErrors=1
;;
;;;; end of directives part ;;;;;
```

What difference does it make to use the semicolons in the beginning of each line? Also some lines have more than one semicolon, why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The semicolon is a standard delimiter in batch files - along with **`<space>`**,**`<tab>`**,**`=`**,**`,`**. So for the batch file it means blank space.

But this is a kind of [polyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)) script - it also a valid [**makecab directive**](https://ss64.com/nt/makecab-directives.html) where the `;` means a comment. It is like that in order to reduce IO operations and make the script a little bit faster and to avoid not so easy to read `echo something>temp.file` lines as much as possible. Some lines are with more semicolons in order to emphasize the real comment lines.

Same trick can be used also with [reg files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php#Self-contained)

Comment: In this method the Batch code becomes complicated in order to make the creation of the MakeCab directives file simpler; however, there are many Batch people that will be confused by this trick and few MakeCab users that can appreciate it. IMHO the creation of the directives file via standard Batch code would be the right choice...

Answer (score 0):

I have only touched upon batch programming to perform simple functions, so I may be wrong, but I have never come across using semicolons at the start of a line. I assume this was done to essentially comment out the lines. If I were you I wouldn't focus on this as you continue to program with batch files.