# Use makecab to zip a whole folder

Tags: zip, directory, filenames, makecab

I see there is a nice way in this post

[How can I compress (/ zip ) and uncompress (/ unzip ) files and folders with batch file without using any external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat/28043695#28043695)

to zip the folder using makecab. One problem with the above script is it can't handle long file name (with long extension name). Fox example, if I have a file with file name, somelongfilename.extension, after I zip and unzip, the filename will be SOMELO~1.EXT. Can anybody direct me a way to fix it?

Comment: PS. I am a newbie on stackoverflow and can't add a comment on the above post. Can somebody help me do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar thing lately. But I use an external tool called DDFGenerator. It's free and small, and it handles long file name properly.

To compress structured folders and files with makecab.exe, a DDF file is a must. Instead of using the batch script mentioned in the answer you quoted, I used DDFGenerator for the same goal.

[DDFGenerator on CodePlex](https://ddfgenerator.codeplex.com/releases/view/18486)

Say, the folder you want to "zip" locates at C:\MyFolder\MyData , use this command to generate a DDF file named "solution.ddf" at C:\MyFolder:

```
DDFGenerator "C:\MyFolder"
```

Note that DDFGenerator.exe iterate files "under" the folder you provides, so to compress C:\MyFolder\MyData, you should pass "C:\MyFolder" to it and make sure MyData is the only item in C:\MyFolder.

After the solution.ddf has been generated, a small tweak is necessary. Just open the "solution.ddf" with any text editor you prefer and make these changes:

Replace these 2 lines (at the very beginning):

```
.Set DiskDirectoryTemplate=CDROM
.Set CompressionType=MSZIP
```

To be:

```
.Set CabinetName1={YourCabName}.cab
.Set CompressionType=LZX
.Set CabinetFileCountThreshold=0
.Set FolderFileCountThreshold=0
.Set FolderSizeThreshold=0
.Set MaxCabinetSize=0
.Set MaxDiskFileCount=0
.Set MaxDiskSize=0
```

(Replace {YourCabName} to whatever suit your needs)
These changes ensure no splitting and with better compression ratio.

Then, run the makecab command at C:\MyFolder to build the cab:

```
makecab.exe /F solution.ddf
```

The {YourCabName}.cab will be located under C:\MyFolder\disk1 after done. Just take it and delete other files that have been generated.

To "unzip" the cab at current path, use command:

```
expand {YourCabName}.cab /F:* .
```