# How to create a batch file that will zip few different files in one .zip file

Tags: batch-file, zip, compression

I want to create a batch/shell script for windows and mac that will take few different files with different types and will compress it to a .zip file.

**I already saw a few questions and answers about it, but all of them either compress all the files in the folder or compress them individually.**

Example (look at attached image):
I have a folder that contains 1.txt, 2.xml, a sub directory.
And I want to turn all of them into a .zip file.

If possible to get a solution both for windows and Mac.

[image: example]

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat) and [this](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-compress-and-uncompress-files-and-folders-in-os-x-lion-10-7-using-terminal/)

Comment: I'm currently using the following command:
 for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
The problem is that it's making each file / directory into an individual zip file. any suggestions to edit it?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows there is the file `7zip.chm` in directory `%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip` which is the help file of 7-Zip. Double click on this file to open the help.

On **Contents** tab there is the list item **Command Line Version** with the help pages:

- *Syntax* ... Command Line Syntax
- *Commands* ... Command Line Commands
- *Switches* ... Command Line Switches

The target is to compress everything in folder `test` into a ZIP file with name of the folder as file name.

This could be done for example with the command line:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -bd -mx=9 -r -y -- test.zip "C:\Path to Directory\test\*"
```

This command line **adds** (**a**) everything in directory `C:\Path to Directory\test` recursive (**-r**) to a ZIP file with name `test.zip` in current working directory without progress indicator (**-bd**) using best ZIP compression (**-mx=9**) with assuming *Yes* on all queries (**-y**).

In other words the file `test.zip` in current directory contains after execution the subdirectory `main` with everything inside and the files `1.txt` and `2.xml`.