# How to zip files using windows compression functionality

Tags: batch-file

How to zip files using windows compression functionality. Don't want to use 3rd party software like winzip,7zip etc. 
Need to do from batch file.

Please help.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compress (/ zip ) and uncompress (/ unzip ) files and folders with batch file without using any external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat)