# Batch rename .zip file to the name of it's contents

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to rename my .zip files as the name of their contents?

For example, my .zip files are named things like `5699302394mpnasth.zip` but the inside of them is associated directly with a shapefile (for qgis) as something like `120345` and these are the file names that I know. Is there anyway I can rename the .zip?

I tried `ren c:\location\*.zip "c:\location\(directory of the inside of the zip)\"zip`

But I didn't have any luck. I am brand new to this and just messing around.

Comment: take a look here and list option of zipjs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [***zipjs.bat***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) in the same directory

```
set "zip_file=C:\567.zip"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('zipjs.bat list -source "%zip_file%" -flat no^|find /i ".qgis"') do set "new_name=%%a"

ren "%zip_file%" "%new_name%.zip"
```

if you want to iterate more files you'll need to wrap this in one more [for loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) and [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Thanks! I have it set up as a folder using the program Directory Monitor. Currently the file just unzips things, but I am going to try adding this script so it will both unzip and rename.

I used this tutorial to set up my folder  http://www.guidingtech.com/24662/automatically-extract-zip-files/