# Batch file to zip folders with original names

Tags: batch-file, zip

I saw the other links for some solutions but, I need to run the script for every folder under a main one but to give it its original name.

Example:

```
Main folder
    Folder 1
Folder 2
Folder 3
```

To output (in the same main folder)

```
Main folder
    Folder 1.zip
Folder 2.zip
Folder 3.zip
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat

Comment: Please read carefully ==> [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
==> [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
==> [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
===> [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [***zipjs.bat***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) in the same directory as this piece of code:

```
@echo off

::Alter the line bellow with your parent directory
set "parent_dir=C:\Parrent\"

for /d %%a in ("%parent_dir%\*") do (
  call zipjs.bat zipItem -source "%%~fa"  -destination "%%~fa.zip" -keep yes -force no
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution for this. Suppose you have multiple sub folders to be zipped in a folder. In that case,
1. Download and lnstall 7zip software. Then copy 7z.exe to the particular folder where you want to zip your subfolders.

in a notepad, copy and paste the following and save as .bat file. :

```
 cd "your_MainFolder_path"
```

`for /d %%f in  do (7z a -t7z %%f.7z "your_mainFolder_path\%%f")`

In case you want to keep the zip files and remove the original folders, add this after the for statement :

```
rd /s /q "your_mainFolder_path\%%f"
```