# 'tar' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: batch-file, zip, windows-10, tar

I am trying to extract a zip file in Windows 10 using a batch script.
It a simple command:

```
 tar zxf "logstash-5.4.0.tar.gz"
 ECHO "installed"
```

But I am getting following error:

**`'tar' is not recognized as an internal or external command`**

I have seen that I have to install the `tar` but how can I do that?

How can I do this?

**EDIT** Tar is pre installed in windows or we have to externally add it? Still how can i extract without using third party tool.

Comment: So you don't want to use a third-party `unzip` program, but you're willing to use a third-party `tar` program? That doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Nope, `tar` has never been a standard tool in Windows. It is on Unix and Unix-like systems though.

Comment: [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) Well, in real you want to extract a GZ archive file which inside contains a TAR archive file. So you need to run in real a double extraction process. Windows has no built-in support for GZ and TAR archives. You need third-party tools like 7-Zip or WinRAR (or Total Commander with additional GZ and TAR packer plugins) to extract such Unix archives on Windows.

Comment: 7-Zip is installed with a manual. Double click on file __7zip.chm__ to open this help file (manual) containing all information about how to use 7-Zip from command line with appropriate command for creation of archive files or extracting files from inside an archive file with appropriate options. A ZIP file can be opened in Windows Explorer like a directory. Just double click on the file. From command line without usage of third-party tools see [How can I compress and uncompress files and folders with batch file without using any external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download **Tartool** Application in your desktop and paste it into 
C:\Windows\system32\

**For eg:-**(C:\Windows\system32\tartool.exe)

By doing this it work as internal command when you want to extract your file you can simply use

**C:>TarTool.exe D:\sample.tar.gz ./**

For more commands you can read documention part of that Tool

Comment: then following command worked to extract tar content from the .tgz:
TarTool.exe "D:\Directory Name\archive.tgz" C:\
(quotation marks because the space in the path. It not accepted parameters like -xzf. Note that the tool require also some other file that is in the archive to be in System32)

Answer (score 0):

Starting windows 10 build 17063, TAR is an inbuilt tool and no need to install it separately. [MSDN link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409)

*For example, to uninstall a file named XYZ.zip you can execute the following in Command Prompt.*

```
tar -xvf XYZ.zip
```