# Unzip with same folder name and should have all files (.bat command lines)

Tags: batch-file

I have three zipped folders inside that sub folders so i want to .bat or cmd file commands to extract folders with same name and should contain all files of sub folders can anyone help me.
eg: xyz.zip,abc.zip,mno.zip
i want to unzip all 3 and folders should be xyz,abc,mno
xyz should contain all files present in sub folders of xyz. similarly for abc,mno

Comment: Please clarify the question. It is not clear what "that" refers to. Also "to .bat" is not verb.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat