# Batch file to archive important files into a zip file in Windows 7

Tags: date, batch-file, windows-7, zip

I have some files which I would like to be able to archive daily into a zip file that has the date in the filename.

The files to be archived are in one folder, let's call them a, b and c.
I would like them to be zipped into a file with the name archiveYYYYMMDD.zip into a second (different) folder where YYYYMMDD is the current date. I'm struggling to come up with a suitable batch file.

I'm running Windows 7 x64 Ultimate. I have a scheduling program which would run the batch file at a preset time every day.

Thanks

Alan

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-datetime-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format/19799236#19799236) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with shareware archiver *WinRAR* with a single command line:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -afzip -agYYYYMMDD -cfg- -ed -ep1 -ibck -inul -m5 -r -y -- "Path to Backup Folder\Backup_.zip" "Path to Folder to Backup\"
```

This single command line can be executed directly as scheduled task. There is no need for a batch file.

The help of *WinRAR* opened by starting *WinRAR* and clicking in menu **Help** on menu item **Help topics** explains under **Contents** menu item **Command line mode** the *command line syntax*, the *command* `a` and the used *switches*.