# Windows Batch Compressed file is Invalid

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip

I have a batch file that compresses files into a `zip` folder so I can email the file. The file runs with no issues. However, when I try to open the `zip` folder, I get the following error:

> 'Folder is invalid'

and it won't open. Below is the part of the step that compresses the file on `Windows Server 2012`:

```
COMPRESS "%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\SP_Backups\Outbound_GDC_Req.txt" "%DIR_IP_INTERFACES%\SP_Backups\Outbound_GDC_Req_%DATE:/=%_%TIME::=%.zip"
```

I need it to `zip` during the batch file, but I will not be the one unzipping. So, I was looking for a standard way to allow anybody to open/unzip the folder when they receive the email (that doesn't require multiple downloads/changes on each computer that might open these files).

Any ideas?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat) .

Comment: compress does not create a `zip` but a `cab`  file

Comment: @npocmaka Thanks for the compress cab file info. I didn't know that. As for your link, the 2003 Admin Tool Pack doesn't work on 64 bit Server. Also, the ZIP.CMD and UNZIP.CMD links are no longer available

Comment: @rbaskins, strange.  I use a lot of the tools in it on all my 64 bit servers and desktops.

Comment: @Squashman It allows me to download it, but the zip.cmd still does not work. I think the issue isn't the 64 bit. After more looking, I believe it is because I am trying to run on a Server 2012 R2

Comment: @rbaskins - probably zipjs.bat is the most portable way to zip your files. I'll have to update the info concerning Frank Westlake's scripts.

Comment: @rbaskins, the `Zip.cmd` has nothing to do with the Windows 2003 Admin Tools.

Comment: @npocmaka Ok, I will look into trying that out. Thanks

Comment: @Squashman oh ok. So what would be the reason for zip.cmd returning that it is not a recognized internal/external command, operable program, or batch file? Do I need to provide access/permissions for it that I am unaware of?