# What is windows default command when zipping a folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip

When I zip files within windows 10, I perform the following steps....

*right click → Send to → Compressed (zipped) folder*

I've been trying to replicate this command but I'm unable to figure out what windows is actually doing to build the .zip folder. I've tried many examples using [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7) which it does zip a folder, but it doesn't seem to be the same default command used by windows.

What command is windows using to zip a folder?

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat  - there's no default command that performs zipping like the right-click ,but you can invoke it using the [zipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) like in the answer.

Comment: Windows 10 also comes with `tar` now in case that's more your style

Comment: This *Send To* context menu item is a file at `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` with the name `Compressed (zipped) folder.ZFSendToTarget`; in the Windows Registry (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`) you can look up the file extension (a key with the name `.ZFSendToTarget`) to find out what actually happens...

Answer (score 2):

In powershell you can use `Compress-Archive -Path input.txt -DestinationPath output.zip` or just `Compress-Archive input.txt output.zip` where `input.txt` can also be a folder. To call a powershell command from Windows Command Prompt add a "powershell" to the start of the command which in this case ou would use `powershell Compress-Archive input.txt output.zip` if you are going to use it in Windows Command Prompt. Yousaid that you were successful doing this in Powershell so just use the same syntax but with an added "powershell" at the beginning of the command in cmd.

For more information or if you are experiencing issues check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-5.1 again