# How to zip multiple folders using Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, zip

i have below Batch file script.

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

This creates zip files of all 10 folders but it creates subfolder in zip file with same name and i dont want that. direct files should be visible in zip file.
is there any way to edit above script to solve this problem.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat  - give me few minutes to add a script as an answer...

Comment: i have below Batch file script.
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
this creates zip files of all 10 folders but it creates subfolder in zip file with same name and i dont want that. direct files should be visible in zip file.
is there any way to edit that script to solve this problem.

Comment: so you don't want the folder itself but only the files?

Comment: zip files of all 10 folder should be created separately and the above does for me but when i open that zip file there is additional folder in it with same name. and i dont want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, the easiest way to perform the task is to first step into each directory, *(to make it 'current')*, zip everything in the current directory, *(default)*, then step back out again.

```batch-file
@For /D %%G In (*)Do @PushD "%%G"&&"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "..\%%G.zip" -r&PopD
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a text file, and copy and paste the following:

```
START /W powershell Compress-Archive folder-name foldername.zip
START powershell Move-Item -Path "path-of-the-zipped-file" -Destination "path-you-want-the-file-to-be-moved-to"`
```

Save as `zip.bat`

Answer (score 1):

check [zipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat). Try to put your folders in a list like in the example bellow (`zipjs.bat` should be in the same directory):

```
@echo off

set "folders_list=C:\folder1;C:\folder2;C:\folder3"
set "destination=C:\my.zip"

del "%destination%" /Q /F >nul 2>&1

for %%a in ("%folders_list%:;=";"%") do (
  if not exist "%destination%" (
    call zipjs.bat zipItem -source "%%~fa" -destination "%destination%" -force no
  ) else (
    call zipjs.bat addToZip -source  "%%~fa" -destination "%destination%" -force no
  )

)
```

EDIT. After some clarifications made by the OP:

```
@echo off

set "folders_list=C:\folder1;C:\folder2;C:\folder3"
set "destination=C:\my.zip"

del "%destination%" /Q /F >nul 2>&1

for %%a in ("%folders_list%:;=";"%") do (
  if not exist "%destination%" (
    call zipjs.bat zipDirItems -source "%%~fa" -destination "%destination%" -force no
  ) else (
    for %%# in ("%%a\*") do (
       call zipjs.bat addToZip -source  "%%~f#" -destination "%destination%" -force no
    )
  )

)
```