# Run multiple start commands in batch file

Tags: java, android, windows, batch-file, command

i have multiple starts commands in batch file and i want to run command one by one. how can i achieve it?

first command generate apk files and other command renamed that file. i want to run first command if it completes then run second commands. and close the command prompt.

```
@echo off

start cmd /k "java -jar "C:\Users\Downloads\bundletool.jar" build-apks --bundle="C:\Users\Downloads\app-live-release.aab" --output="C:\Users\Downloads\NWorkingApp.apks" --mode=universal --ks="C:\Users\Downloads\NWorkingApp.keystore" --ks-pass="pass:NWorkingAppio99" --ks-key-alias="nworking" --key-pass="pass:NWorkingAppio99""

start ren "C:\Users\Downloads\*.apks" "*.zip"

pause
```

I am expecting the commands which run both commands

Comment: The solution is replacing everything you have in the entire batch file by the single command line: `@java.exe -jar "C:\Users\Downloads\bundletool.jar" build-apks --bundle="C:\Users\Downloads\app-live-release.aab" --output="C:\Users\Downloads\NWorkingApp.apks" --mode=universal --ks="C:\Users\Downloads\NWorkingApp.keystore" --ks-pass="pass:NWorkingAppio99" --ks-key-alias="nworking" --key-pass="pass:NWorkingAppio99" & ren "C:\Users\Downloads\*.apks" "*.zip"`

Comment: __Note:__ If the `.apks` files should be really ZIP compressed into ZIP archive files, there must be a different command used than `ren` which just changes the file extension without changing the file contents and therefore not creating ZIP archive files. Look on [How can I compress (/ zip ) and uncompress (/ unzip ) files and folders with batch file without using any external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/)